# FFMpeg Force Codec

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I am dealing with a video that as a codec tag of `none`, but the actual codec is `GHEC`.  I am aware this is a proprietary codec from GeoVision.  The video will not play unless I use ffplay with the `-vcodec hevc` argument.  Since `GHEC` codec will play via `hevc` codec, is there any way I can force the codec to be `hevc` on this video so I can watch it in other media players like VLC?

Here are the streams from ffprobe:

```
    Stream #0:0: Video: none (GHEC / 0x43454847), none, 1920x1080, 451 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Subtitle: none, 3 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: none
```

Comment: Remux via ffmpeg with the decoder specified.

Comment: @Gyan anything I try keeps giving me this error: `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`.  I have tried `ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec:hevc out.avi`, `ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec hevc out.avi`, and `ffmpeg -i -c:v codec hevc out.avi`.  Are my commands correct?

Comment: Got it, looks like it `-c:v hevc` must come before the `-i` argument.

Comment: @Gyan If you want to answer my question I can accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the compatible codec in ffmpeg, you can remux the file to generate a standard file, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -c:v hevc -i in.avi -c copy out.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI - you can't just force a codec if the `moov atom` or `headers` are missing.

For that you need to repair the file by copying valid headers and atoms from another functional file created the same way.

The only utility that worked for me was https://codecpack.co/download/recover-mp4.html - which gives instructions when run without arguments, runs fine on `wine`, and worked, unlike `untrunc` and a bunch of other ffpmeg-based utilities.

(The file is archived here: http://web.archive.org/web/20220320003709/https://download1491.mediafire.com/u39upc91ggmg/yf8ct3b58ipbc3l/recover_mp4.zip)